# DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, orm

I'm usign Spring ORM with Hibernate, and when I write the command

```
hibernateTemplate.save(entityInstance);
```

(entityInstance is obviously an instance of a User entity)

I get this error:

```
The type org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

Even though i followed a (working) tutorial step-by-step (and code-by-code) it doesn't work.
This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.dsystems</groupId>
<artifactId>newtokenmanager</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>newtokenmanager Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.45</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Eclipse also suggests me as 'quick fix' to configure build path from the menu, but I don't know exactly what to do. 
As some people suggested for similar issues here on SO, I tried by removing and reloading both JRE System Library and Maven dependencies, but didn't work.

Comment: How did you import the project into eclipse?

Comment: I didn't import it. I created it from a Maven Archetype (web mvc) and followed the tutorial.

Comment: If you expand the Maven Dependencies folder under your project, do you see the spring-tx jar?

Comment: Yes, version 5.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: try doing a mvn clean install on your project, as it looks like you are trying to refer to one of the spring jars which aren't in your project build path. Also do a Project->Clean & set enable Build Automatically in eclipse.

Comment: You can try cleaning the project by selecting the project then clicking Project->Clean at the top. What tutorial are you following?

Comment: @twinklehawk a tutorial about spring on udemy called "Spring framework in easy steps". I tried twice but nothing...

Comment: @robot_alien The mvn clean install command says "No compiler is provided in this environment. Perhaps you are running on a JRE rather than a JDK?" even though I am using JDK (tried also to use JRE instead but it's the same). As I said to twinklehawk I did Project > Clean twice. Also, "Build automatically" was enabled since the beginning.

Comment: Did you do the mvn clean install from the command line or from inside eclipse? If you did it inside eclipse, does it work from the command line?

Comment: I did it from the command line.

Comment: Ok, in your eclipse, go to Window-> Preferences-> Java -> Installed JREs-> check your installed JRE. You should have an entry with a JDK there. If no, please add one... Once that's done, do Project rt click Maven -> Update Project. Let me know if it worked for you...!

Comment: Well, jdk was already checked... So I tried by doing that procedure with Jre and then changing it again with jdk... Nothing happened.
I also tried by downgrading hibernate to 5.1.x because i noticed that 5.2.x is still in development, but still no change.
I was wondering, why does eclipse suggest me as 'quick fix' to change the build path? I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download jar from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadspringdao206jar.htm)

import into your project, it will resolve.

Your HibernateTemplate class is importing `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` class which is not present in your classpath.

Answer (score 8):

Add in pom for Maven project

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

or add jar spring-tx

Answer (score 0):

spring-tx.jar because I got this error:

The type org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. 
It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
TestSpring.java

spring-core.jar because I got this error:

The type org.springframework.core.NestedRuntimeException 
cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files 
TestSpring.java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Maybe it's just me, but I can't figure out how this answers the question. Could you maybe explain it a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

The type `org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException` cannot be resolved. for this error add the spring jar in classpath `spring-tx-x.x.x.RELEASE.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the dependency for **spring-dao** and build your project once.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```