# org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, maven

The type org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files UserAPIController.java  demo/web/src/main/java/controller

how to resolve this issue?

I added all Spring jars, but still getting same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795169/dataaccessexception-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly-referenced-from-require